# scalr api with postman client an

Tags: postman, scalr

I am working on scalr and trying to access scalr api using postman client but I have getting error:

```
 {

  "meta": {
        "requestId": "63b814f1-f885-48cc-85d6-762e524e0bfb"
      },
      "errors": [
        {
          "code": "BadAuthentication",
          "message": "Unsigned request"
        }
      ]
    }
```

For scalr api they have given Access keyid:xxxxxxx  and secret key: xxxxxxxx so I am using basic auth for authentication process and giving:

```
username:(scale key id)
password:(scalr secret_key)
```

Scalr apis working fine with scalr api interface but throwing error with postman client. 
Please suggest me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the API v1 (deprecated) that is currently available in Scalr Open Source, you need to get the signature from your user profile as [described in the documentation](https://scalr-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/display/docs/API+Authentication).

If you are using Scalr Enterprise which supports the current API v2, authentication is described in the [API Explorer](https://api-explorer.scalr.com/authentication/index.html).